# Minimalistic PHP template engine with caching but not Smarty?

Tags: php, templates, caching, smarty

There are [loads of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+template+engine+cache) for "the right" PHP template engine, but none of them is focused on caching.

Does anybody know a lightweight, high-quality, PHP 5 based template engine that does the following out of the box:

- Low-level templating functions (Replacements, loops, and filtering, maybe conditionals)
- Caching of the parsed results with the possibility to set an individual TTL per item, and of course to force a reload programmatically
- Extremely easy usage (like Smarty's)
- Modest in polluting the namespace (the ideal solution would be one class to interact  with from the outside application)

But **not Smarty**. I have nothing against, and often use, Smarty, but I am looking for something a bit simpler and leaner.

I took a look at Fabien Potencier's [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/) that looks very nice and compiles templates into PHP code, but it doesn't do any actual caching beyond that.

I *need* and *want* a template engine, as I need to completely separate code and presentation in a way that a HTML designer can understand later on, so please no fundamental discussions about whether template engines in PHP make sense. Those discussions are important, but there are specific questions for that issue.

Comment: *(overview)* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29

Comment: *(german overview)* http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_Engine#PHP_Template_Engines

Comment: You could try looking into [Dwoo](http://dwoo.org/) which is supposed to be an updated cleaner Smarty with very high compatibility between the two. Besides that I think you're best off taking Alfred's advice and writing something to cache Twig for you.

Comment: @Pekka: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+minimalistic Are you trying to take over the world with minimalistic stuff? xP

Comment: @Alix ssssshhhhh! It's supposed to be a secret. :) I'm also looking for ways to run a minimalistic military dictatorship. Any links, anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Template Engine with Caching

- To answer your question I don't know
  a template which support all your requirements. Hopefully somebody else can help you with that. But after a little bit of searching I found [TinyButStrong](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/). On there site they mention it has a `cache system`. I can't find what kind of caching they implement(Disc/Memory/Database). It should cache in memory for truly speedups).

### Implement Caching yourself

- I believe that Twig is a pretty solid
  template enine and that you can
  implement caching on top of that
  easily.
- Just cache it in [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php). When
  [storing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) put a TTL(Time To Live)
  on it of. Then try to [get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-fetch.php) it
  from cache.
- I assume you already have APC
  installed, if you are concerned about
  performance (caching). Then the
  first thing you should install for
  performance is APC(A **must** because it also stores compiled PHP files in memory. This means it does not have to recompile every time). If you can not install APC then maybe you could check out
  [Cache-Lite](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.caching.cache-lite.intro.php). I really liked this pear package for it's simplicity/good documentation.

Comment: I ended up using Twig. Thanks!